# "Unable to locate package" error in Crunchbang

Tags: debian, installation, package-management

I am running Crunchbang as a virtual machine. I ran
`sudo apt-get update` and then `sudo apt-get install calibre`. It says

> E: Unable to locate package

How to resolve this? I have already tried the steps mentioned here but to no avail.
https://www.tecmint.com/fix-unable-to-locate-package-error-in-debian-9/

When I replace `calibre` by `vim` or `evince` or `openssh-server`, it says there is no installation candidate.

Comment: What repositories are set up in this system? Is Caliber available on those repositories?

Comment: @music2myear deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security main contrib non-free

deb [trusted=yes] http://deb.debian.org/debian main stretch contrib non-free
deb-src [trusted=yes] http://deb.debian.org/debian main stretch contrib non-free

(Contents of /etc/apt/sources.list)
No clue if calibre is available in these repositories. Is there a way to check? I am a novice, don't know much about linux :-(

Comment: Use the Edit button to add this and any other requested information to the question itself, not as comments. This makes your question better and increases the chance of a good answer.